# Pass additional object to CreateMap

Tags: c#, automapper

My object mapping requires me to pass the source object and an additional object to be able to map the destination object appropriately. However, I am unable to determine a way to be able to get that done.

```
public class SourceDto
{
    public string Value1 { get; set; }
    public string Value2 { get; set; }
    public string SourceValue3 { get; set; }
    public string SourceValue4 { get; set; }
}

public class AnotherSourceDto
{
    public string AnotherSourceValue1 { get; set; }
    public string AnotherSourceValue2 { get; set; }
    public string AnotherSourceValue3 { get; set; }
    public string AnotherSourceValue4 { get; set; }
}

public class Destination
{
    public string Value1 { get; set; }
    public string Value2 { get; set; }
    public string DestValue3 { get; set; }
}

public string ConvertToDestValue3(string sourceValue3, string anotherSourceValue2)
{
    // Some logic goes here
    return sourceValue3 + " " + anotherSourceValue2;
}


void Main()
{

    var config = new MapperConfiguration(
    cfg =>cfg.CreateMap<SourceDto, Destination>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.DestValue3, 
    opt => opt.MapFrom(
        src => ConvertToDestValue3(src.SourceValue3, "" //Here I need to pass AnotherSourceDto.AnotherSourceValue2 ))));
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid the answer is to map that property outside AutoMapper.

Here's an example where you could do this using an extension method, so it still has the look and feel of being done with AutoMapper.

```
// put inside a static class
public static Destination CustomMap(
    this IMapper mapper,
    SourceDto source,
    AnotherSourceDto anotherSource)
{
    var destination = mapper.Map<Destination>(source);
    destination.DestValue3 =
        source.SourceValue3 + " " + anotherSource.AnotherSourceValue2;
    return destination;
}

void Main()
{
    var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        cfg.CreateMap<SourceDto, Destination>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.DestValue3, opt => opt.Ignore()));

    // usage
    var mapper = config.CreateMapper();
    var source = new SourceDto { /* add properties */ };
    var anotherSource = new AnotherSourceDto { /* add properties */ };
    var destination = mapper.CustomMap(source, anotherSource);
}
```

Comment: This option looks more clean. I actually have implemented it as a normal method, I am going to use this idea. Thank you